# Using Rwanda and Seychelles for travel History, Good Idea or bad Idea?

Tags: international-travel, nigerian-citizens

I wonna ask something about Travel history. I have been denied visas twice and hence i decided to seek travel history and then return so I can re apply again after sometime.
Must it be the EU? I am considering Moving to Rwanda for vacation and come home and then Seychelles and come back home again. Now i wanted to ask, If i am on track. Please I do need advises

Comment: Denied visas for where? What were you denied for?

Comment: @BritishSam, i was Denied visas for Canada, said i did not have travel history

Comment: Travel history cannot be the only reason. People successfully get visas who have never left the country. You should focus on the other reasons; they are much more important.

Comment: Said i did not satisfy them that I would return , based on travel history. That's the information stated there.

Comment: What ties to your home country do you have? Job, dependent family etc? While building up a travel history should help over time, it’s unlikely to be enough to change the outcome of an application to Canada (particularly if it’s only to countries with a relaxed entry policy) unless you can also demonstrate a compelling reason to leave Canada at the end of your visit.

Comment: I have a Job here as a Banker. I have someone I am looking to get married to, and some landed properties etc. Please when you speak of relaxed entry policy, what you imply pls @Traveller

Comment: @Tadel I’m referring to countries that allow visa free or visa on arrival entry to the majority of visitors. A short travel history that only includes such countries may not count for much when applying to countries with a stricter entry policy.

Comment: @Traveller, Are u saying Seychelles may be a bad idea afterall, because for us Nigerian citizens, Seychelles is visa free. Mauritius is visa on arrival for 14 days. kindly advise.

Comment: No, I’m not saying that. Any travel history is better than none. I’m saying that a record of visiting Rwanda, Seychelles, Mauritius etc does not guarantee or necessarily make it more likely that you’ll get a visitor visa for Canada (or equivalent regimes, such as Schengen, Australia, UK).

Comment: @Traveller, Where do you have in mind one can visit in my case.

Answer (score 4):

Your visa was hardly refused for lack of international travel experience.

I guess you were issued something like this (with not the same boxes checked):

> [image: Rejection letter sample]

The official making the decision was obviously not satisfied that you would leave Canada in time. This would have been an overall assessment, based on all available relevant information. That your travel history was considered does not say how it affected the decision, if at all.

In any case, you need to convince the Canadians that you will not overstay, by providing new information. You will not achieve that by travelling to random countries.

Comment: How can I prove that? I included my employment letter where I work and the remote job I do (Work as a Software Developer Remote and I work on site as a Software Engineer as well), I also included my ID Card from my office, included Payslips and bank statements (Salary account and business account), Landed properties, the only thing i did not include was the part of international travel (I do not have that yet, and I do not have to tell lie.)

Comment: I even made provision for Sworn affidavits at court detailing my landed properties and all. As well as several other documentations detailing my business, Registered business Documents and everything. Now i am just wondering why else. So the only worry is I do not have a travel history as I see it